# Getting key value pairs out of xml file with query

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I exported my iTunes library to an xml file, it sort of looks like this:

```
<key>725</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Track ID</key><integer>725</integer>
        <key>Name</key><string>Sandstorm</string>
        <key>Artist</key><string>Daro</string>
        <key>Album</key><string>Gunther D</string>
        <key>Genre</key><string>Dance</string>
        <key>Kind</key><string>MPEG-audiobestand</string>
        <key>Size</key><integer>6937997</integer>
        <key>Total Time</key><integer>223451</integer>
        <key>Track Number</key><integer>3</integer>
        <key>Year</key><integer>2013</integer>
        <key>Library Folder Count</key><integer>1</integer>
    </dict>
```

I did my ajax call to read out the xml file. But now I want to get the album key and the string but i don't know how to get to it.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
url: "Bibliotheek.xml",
dataType: "xml",
success: function(data){
    var $xml = $(data);
    var $key = $xml.find('key').each(function(){
        console.log($key);

        });
    }    
});
```

});

Now it logs all my keys in my console, but i just want the album key

Comment: can u make fiddle  ( http://jsfiddle.net/)????

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=hFuP2i2ci3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the keys

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url      : "Bibliotheek.xml",
        dataType : "xml",
        success  : function(data){

            var album = $(data).find('key').filter(function() {
                return $(this).text().indexOf('Album') != -1;
            }).next('string').text();

        }    
    });
});
```

Comment: One last question, if you could help me with it would be nice.
I want to put them all aligned underneath each other, but if I add a <br> tag he keeps on aligning them next to each other

Comment: @adeneo if we have many sets of <dict> and want every dict set key values(string values) printed inside <tr> how we ca achieve that ?Thanks